# Can't create an arrays from .txt file inside a loop

Tags: java, arrays, file-io, nested-loops

I am trying to create a different types of arrays (String, int ...) from a .txt but I face an error message immediately.

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:864)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1485)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2117)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2076)
    at javaapplication12.JavaApplication12.main(JavaApplication12.java:27)
Java Result: 1
```

here is my code :

```js
package javaapplication12;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class JavaApplication12 {

    public static int num = 128;
    public static String[] name = new String[num];
    public static int[] id = new int[num];
    public static int[] year = new int[num];
    public static double[] price = new double[num];
    public static int[] sh = new int[num];
    public static int[] row = new int[num];
    public static int[] col = new int[num];

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        File inputFile = new File("Store.txt");
        Scanner fin = new Scanner(inputFile);
        fin.nextLine();
        fin.nextLine();

        while (fin.hasNext()) {
            for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
                name[i] = fin.next();
                id[i] = fin.nextInt();
                fin.next();
                fin.next();
                fin.next();
                fin.next();
                fin.next();
                year[i] = fin.nextInt();
                price[i] = fin.nextDouble();
                sh[i] = fin.nextInt();
                row[i] = fin.nextInt();
                col[i] = fin.nextInt();

            }
        }

        fin.close();
    }

}
```

I do not understand why does this happen at all since I am all new to coding. Thanks.

Here is the table I am using:

```
           Name      ID                Date in              Price     S  R  C
______________________________________________________________________________
             Saw     562    SAT SEP 30 00:00:00 AST 1950    37.00     2 13  1
    Tape Measure     955    TUE AUG 27 00:00:00 AST 1918    52.00    13  4  4
           Knife      25    TUE MAR 14 00:00:00 AST 2000    31.00     9 15  7
          Chisel     911    WED NOV 18 00:00:00 AST 1992    83.00     6 15  3
           Ruler     837    WED APR 19 00:00:00 AST 1978    32.00    13 13  4
            file     797    MON MAY 07 00:00:00 AST 1934    46.00    13  7  0
           Brush     190    MON SEP 07 00:00:00 AST 1959    48.00     7  3 15
         Scraper     619    WED MAR 14 00:00:00 AST 1900    36.00     3  0  0
           Level     369    SAT MAR 08 00:00:00 AST 1919    78.00    15  9  6
            Vise     487    THU OCT 06 00:00:00 AST 1904    32.00     5  3 13
            Vise     403    FRI JAN 02 00:00:00 AST 1931    87.00    10 12  2
           Brush     683    WED JUL 17 00:00:00 AST 1974    74.00     6 11  5
           Brush     821    THU DEC 26 00:00:00 AST 1929    44.00    12  6 10
    Screw Driver     246    WED SEP 03 00:00:00 AST 1947     8.00    12  0  1
           Knife     296    TUE FEB 10 00:00:00 AST 1914    72.00     9  2  0
           Knife     895    SUN MAY 17 00:00:00 AST 1903    38.00     0  8  7
          Hammer     213    SUN MAY 05 00:00:00 AST 2013    51.00     6  8 12
           Ruler      47    MON JUN 03 00:00:00 AST 1918    42.00     3  0  1
          Chisel     958    FRI OCT 09 00:00:00 AST 1981    70.00     5  7  8
            file     279    WED JAN 20 00:00:00 AST 1999    95.00     6  1  9
           Knife      90    FRI JAN 20 00:00:00 AST 2012    92.00    10  6  0
      Sand Paper     642    SUN FEB 23 00:00:00 AST 1975     6.00     6  8  0
            Vise     410    MON MAR 25 00:00:00 AST 1957    74.00     8 11  1
            file     856    MON MAY 09 00:00:00 AST 2011    20.00    12  6  8
            file     581    MON AUG 04 00:00:00 AST 1930    18.00     5 11  0
           Knife     287    WED FEB 04 00:00:00 AST 1970    96.00    15 13 10
          Wrench     905    SUN FEB 07 00:00:00 AST 1999    32.00     2  0  0
    Tape Measure     744    THU JAN 26 00:00:00 AST 1939    77.00     4 13  4
      Sand Paper     306    TUE JUN 07 00:00:00 AST 1960    82.00     1 15  5
           Brush     901    TUE FEB 08 00:00:00 AST 2000    59.00     6 10 13
           Ruler     180    FRI OCT 18 00:00:00 AST 1907    72.00    10 11  7
          Chisel     633    TUE FEB 22 00:00:00 AST 1916    55.00     9  5  5
    Tape Measure     698    WED DEC 14 00:00:00 AST 1938     8.00    12 10  6
          Wrench     315    THU OCT 22 00:00:00 AST 1925    17.00     0  0  1
          Pliers     912    TUE MAR 08 00:00:00 AST 1904     9.00     8  5  7
          Hammer     216    SAT JUN 27 00:00:00 AST 1914     9.00     1  6  4
            Vise     976    SUN OCT 04 00:00:00 AST 1998    70.00    15  9  0
          Chisel     884    THU APR 11 00:00:00 AST 1901    52.00    10 15  5
             Saw     980    SAT FEB 22 00:00:00 AST 1941    16.00    13 13 11
           Ruler     796    FRI SEP 11 00:00:00 AST 1998    88.00     5  4 15
         Scraper     313    SUN FEB 02 00:00:00 AST 1919    31.00    14  8  7
            file     885    SAT NOV 13 00:00:00 AST 1965    25.00     7  6 12
           Knife     752    TUE OCT 25 00:00:00 AST 1983    60.00     5 11  7
           Knife     470    FRI JUN 07 00:00:00 AST 1957    56.00     6 12  8
          Hammer     148    SUN FEB 28 00:00:00 AST 1965    63.00     5  8 14
            file     974    THU OCT 14 00:00:00 AST 1993    90.00     1  6 12
          Chisel     434    MON OCT 06 00:00:00 AST 1930    94.00     0  5  5
          Hammer     709    FRI SEP 14 00:00:00 AST 1945     3.00     7  6  4
          Pliers     594    SAT MAY 25 00:00:00 AST 1968    19.00     2  7 11
          Hammer     120    TUE AUG 07 00:00:00 AST 1979    40.00     3 10  2
           Ruler     396    SAT MAR 21 00:00:00 AST 1981    42.00     5  7  9
          Hammer     874    FRI MAR 22 00:00:00 AST 1935    82.00     4  8  8
          Chisel     182    SAT NOV 30 00:00:00 AST 1985    86.00    12  7  5
          Hammer     976    SUN MAR 09 00:00:00 AST 1919    83.00    11 14  0
    Tape Measure     750    FRI JUL 09 00:00:00 AST 1920    23.00     2  1  6
    Tape Measure     776    MON JUN 01 00:00:00 AST 1998    21.00    11  3  7
          Hammer     870    THU DEC 23 00:00:00 AST 1993    62.00    10 11 11
    Screw Driver     943    FRI FEB 28 00:00:00 AST 1997    84.00    10  1 13
          Hammer     689    WED FEB 28 00:00:00 AST 1934    82.00    11  8 10
           Brush     816    SAT JAN 31 00:00:00 AST 1953    51.00     1  4 14
         Scraper     500    THU SEP 24 00:00:00 AST 1931    55.00     6  5 12
           Ruler     686    THU MAY 14 00:00:00 AST 1987    17.00    13  6  8
           Brush     675    FRI JUN 09 00:00:00 AST 1922    39.00     7  0  9
      Sand Paper     938    SAT AUG 15 00:00:00 AST 1959    18.00     6  5 15
            Vise     904    WED OCT 01 00:00:00 AST 1986    35.00    12  4 15
           Level     455    FRI DEC 06 00:00:00 AST 1957    42.00    14 13  1
           Knife     999    MON MAR 24 00:00:00 AST 1930    25.00     0  0  4
         Scraper      94    MON NOV 05 00:00:00 AST 1951    22.00     8  2  4
             Saw     473    MON SEP 18 00:00:00 AST 1961    30.00     1  9 13
             Saw     140    THU JAN 27 00:00:00 AST 1921     3.00    13  2  0
    Tape Measure     401    THU AUG 22 00:00:00 AST 1985    81.00     1  4  3
    Screw Driver     923    WED JAN 26 00:00:00 AST 2005    35.00     3 14  2
       Allen Key      87    THU JUL 11 00:00:00 AST 2013    10.00     6  4  1
          Wrench     917    TUE SEP 23 00:00:00 AST 1969    35.00    12 14  8
          Wrench     367    MON AUG 05 00:00:00 AST 1929    99.00     6  3 13
             Saw     484    SAT JUN 12 00:00:00 AST 1926    36.00    10  8  8
    Screw Driver     816    WED JUL 27 00:00:00 AST 1927    13.00    13  1  0
           Ruler     476    TUE DEC 25 00:00:00 AST 1945    92.00    11  6  4
           Brush     762    FRI FEB 19 00:00:00 AST 1937    50.00     2  3  9
    Screw Driver     332    TUE SEP 06 00:00:00 AST 2011    60.00    11  7 12
           Level     849    WED AUG 25 00:00:00 AST 1937    82.00     2  6  6
           Knife     812    TUE NOV 01 00:00:00 AST 1949    58.00    13  8  4
             Saw     810    THU JAN 15 00:00:00 AST 1959     3.00     5  0  2
             Saw     385    SAT SEP 10 00:00:00 AST 1983    55.00     7  0  6
           Knife     626    TUE JUN 30 00:00:00 AST 1936     9.00    14  7 15
    Tape Measure     387    WED FEB 19 00:00:00 AST 2014    89.00    15  8  3
      Sand Paper     987    WED NOV 17 00:00:00 AST 1926    91.00     1 14 15
             Saw     880    WED MAY 13 00:00:00 AST 2009     8.00     6 14 10
      Sand Paper     932    MON JAN 09 00:00:00 AST 1995    72.00     0 14 12
            Vise     598    SUN FEB 11 00:00:00 AST 1951    97.00     3 10  0
         Scraper     369    SUN AUG 08 00:00:00 AST 1943     6.00     5 14 12
       Allen Key     167    SUN DEC 22 00:00:00 AST 1929    54.00    12 14  3
           Knife     725    SAT DEC 16 00:00:00 AST 1961    40.00    13 13 10
          Hammer     444    THU NOV 17 00:00:00 AST 1938    64.00     9 12  8
          Chisel      70    WED SEP 30 00:00:00 AST 1903    31.00     6  2 11
    Tape Measure     785    FRI APR 30 00:00:00 AST 1926    76.00     2  9 13
    Tape Measure     769    THU MAY 25 00:00:00 AST 2000    93.00    12  0 12
          Hammer     877    SAT JUL 16 00:00:00 AST 1977    68.00     1  6  0
          Wrench     802    FRI DEC 31 00:00:00 AST 1915    26.00    15 13  7
          Wrench     297    SAT JUN 12 00:00:00 AST 1976    44.00    12 15  3
            file     159    TUE MAR 21 00:00:00 AST 1967    76.00     3 10 12
       Allen Key     632    FRI MAY 14 00:00:00 AST 1971    29.00    11  6 13
           Level     651    THU FEB 12 00:00:00 AST 2004    70.00     1  6  9
          Wrench     451    MON JUL 19 00:00:00 AST 1982    68.00    10 10  4
    Tape Measure     429    FRI FEB 28 00:00:00 AST 2014    23.00     0  0  7
          Hammer     723    FRI JAN 12 00:00:00 AST 2001    86.00    13 12  5
           Level      89    WED MAY 21 00:00:00 AST 1924    36.00    10 10 14
            file     734    SAT JUL 19 00:00:00 AST 1930    88.00    10 13 14
         Scraper     489    SUN SEP 26 00:00:00 AST 1926    79.00     0  0  4
           Brush     419    FRI OCT 01 00:00:00 AST 1954    88.00    15  1  1
    Tape Measure     990    MON FEB 28 00:00:00 AST 1921    69.00     0  3  8
           Ruler      97    MON AUG 04 00:00:00 AST 1924    38.00     8  5  2
            file     944    SAT MAY 18 00:00:00 AST 1963    94.00     4  8 12
           Ruler     205    SUN DEC 22 00:00:00 AST 1912    95.00     6  0  3
          Chisel     702    TUE APR 14 00:00:00 AST 1936    98.00    15  6  6
            file     388    WED SEP 26 00:00:00 AST 1951    72.00    12  1  3
           Knife     519    WED OCT 25 00:00:00 AST 1989    97.00     4  0  4
          Pliers      90    WED OCT 31 00:00:00 AST 1928    92.00    12  3  1
            file     905    THU SEP 25 00:00:00 AST 1902    15.00     7 10  8
         Scraper     892    MON NOV 04 00:00:00 AST 1912    38.00     7  4  6
           Brush     941    WED SEP 17 00:00:00 AST 2008    52.00    10  6  3
    Screw Driver     196    TUE NOV 19 00:00:00 AST 1918    33.00     1  7  4
            Vise     675    SAT NOV 10 00:00:00 AST 1951    100.00     4  9 10
          Hammer     545    THU AUG 22 00:00:00 AST 1991    51.00    13 14  3
            Vise     240    TUE SEP 17 00:00:00 AST 1935    68.00     8  8 15
    Screw Driver     474    THU FEB 10 00:00:00 AST 1972    38.00     1  6 11
             Saw     602    MON MAY 22 00:00:00 AST 1922    65.00     8 15 14
           Knife     254    TUE JUL 11 00:00:00 AST 1961    76.00    11  1  3
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Keep in mind that Java != Javascript, they're about as similar a car and carpet.

Comment: @Henrykvdb oh, thanks for the info! I think I put it by mistake.

Comment: what the content of your text file?

Comment: Best guess is that the name is 2 words (like "John Smith") and `next()` is only taking "John", and then `nextInt()` is trying to parse "Smith" and that's obviously not an int so it throws an exception.  But without the text file it's impossible to say for sure.

Comment: @YCF_L Just put it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use BufferReader to read line by line, You had a problem in the names, of your check some times your name have one String and sometimes two so for that you get `java.util.InputMismatchException` because you try read int in `id[i] = fin.nextInt();` but this not an int for that you get this error, this can help you :

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, UnsupportedEncodingException, IOException {
    File filePath = new File("Store.txt");
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(filePath), "Cp1252"));

    String line;
    String lineSplit[];
    int i = 0;
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        //replace multiple spapce with one space
        line = line.replaceAll("\\s{2,}", " ").trim();
        //Split the line with space so you can get an Array :
        //like this [Saw, 562, SAT, SEP, 30, 00:00:00, AST, 1950, 37.00, 2, 13, 1]
        //or this   [Tape, Measure, 955, TUE, AUG, 27, 00:00:00, AST, 1918, 52.00, 13, 4, 4]
        lineSplit = line.split(" ");
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(lineSplit));
        //if we notice the Name can contain one String or two so we can check get names like this :
        boolean check = false;
        try {
            Integer.parseInt(lineSplit[1]);
            check = true;
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            check = false;
        }
        if (check) {
            name[i] = lineSplit[0];
            id[i] = Integer.parseInt(lineSplit[1]);
            year[i] = Integer.parseInt(lineSplit[7]);
            price[i] = Double.parseDouble(lineSplit[8]);
            sh[i] = Integer.parseInt(lineSplit[9]);
            row[i] = Integer.parseInt(lineSplit[10]);
            col[i] = Integer.parseInt(lineSplit[11]);
        } else {
            name[i] = lineSplit[0] + " " + lineSplit[1];
            id[i] = Integer.parseInt(lineSplit[2]);
            year[i] = Integer.parseInt(lineSplit[8]);
            price[i] = Double.parseDouble(lineSplit[9]);
            sh[i] = Integer.parseInt(lineSplit[10]);
            row[i] = Integer.parseInt(lineSplit[11]);
            col[i] = Integer.parseInt(lineSplit[12]);
        }
        i++;
    }
    br.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It took me a while to understand the code, but I finally thing I got it.

So, your variable `num` must be the total number of rows in the file and you're trying to build an `array` per field.  If I'm wrong don carry on reading

If I'm right, then your mistake comes from using `nextLine()` and believing it will jump to the next same column value in the next line of the file

When you're using `nextLine()` what you're effectively doing is jumping to the next line of the txt file, which will start with the Name column in your particular case, so come the moment to introduce the int value for the id of the first row as you have it, you are actually trying to give it the value of the Name column from the second row

So the best approach for this is to pick up all values of each row and then try to split them, hopefully you have a comma separated file or you can generate one from the table where you're retrieving your data from

So then you'll be getting an array of String from the file like this:

```
String[]arrayFromTheFile = new String[128];
    int i=0;
    File inputFile = new File("Store.txt");
    Scanner fin = new Scanner(inputFile);
    while (fin.hasNext()) {
    arrayFromTheFile[i] = fin.next();
    i++;
}
fin.close();
```

So now, as long as you're sure the file has 128 rows, you have built your array, if not you will get an `ArrayOutOfBoundsException` which is a whole new experience :)  In fact the best way to do this is dinamically, but as you said you're quite new, let's do it the way they are teaching you to.

For the field splitting in order to populate the other arrays you need to use the `split()` method and use whichever character may be in between the fields.  I will leave that for you to investigate ;)